# critical region explanation from this sentence

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> Any section of code that should be finished by each process that
>   begins it before another process can enter it is called a critical
>   region.

i'm trying to understand the meaning but it's too complicated.
can anyone simplify this?
it's from "Understanding the linux kernel" by O'Rilley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the main part of the sentence:

> **Any section of code** that should be finished by each process that begins it before another process can enter it **is called a critical region**.

What kind of section of code is it?
It's a section of code that:

> **should be finished** by each process that begins it **before another process can enter it**

In other words, a **critical region** is any section of code that if a process begins it, that process should finish it before any other process can enter it (i.e., that section of code; that critical region).

Answer (score 1):

> {*Any section of code*}<sub>subject</sub> {that should be finished by each process {that begins ***it***}<sub>rel.clause</sub> before {another process can enter ***it***}<sub>rel.clause</sub>}<sub>rel.clause</sub> {is called}<sub>predicate</sub> {a critical region}<sub>object</sub>.

Perhaps the only really complicated part of it is the nested subordinate clauses:

> that should be finished by each process {that begins ***it***}<sub>rel.clause</sub> before {another process can enter ***it***}<sub>rel.clause</sub>

In the original sentence the "***it***" (appearing twice) refers to "any section of code" (the main subject).

The contracted version might be

> Any section of code {*that has some special requirements*}<sub>rel.clause</sub> is called a critical section.

The special requirements are expressed by the nested clauses extracted above.